# Delphi casting with as and Supports difference

Tags: delphi, interface, casting, com

What is the difference in casting using `Supports` vs `as` keyword, besides that with `as` I first need to check if cast is possible with `is` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Supports` will provide an interface if that interface is supported.

`is` determines if a class/interface derives from another class/interface.

`as` does the same thing as `is`, but also returns a type-checked cast.

If you have already confirmed with `is` that a cast will succeed, you don't need to use `as`, you can just do a direct cast, which is more efficient:

```pascal
if(pSomeObjectRef is TMyObject) then
  TMyObject(pSomeObjectRef).MyUsefulMethod(...);
```

As Delphi does not support multiple inheritance, using interfaces is the only way to implement that kind of behavior. An object which can be more than one thing, not just itself or its ancestors.

If you're not using interfaces, you shouldn't need to use `Supports()`.

Using `as` to cast allows you to cast an object reference to an interface, as well as to a reference to a different class of object. Personally, I don't use `as`, and I rarely see it in the code I'm looking at. Since `as` can raise an exception, you ought to take steps to avoid the exceptions, and catch them if they are raised. As you can check these anyway, there should never be a need to use `as`.

When casting to an interface, rather than relying on the exception to catch the interface not being there, you can use the result of `Supports()`:

```pascal
if (SysUtils.Supports(pSomeObjectRef, IMyWantedInterface, diInterfaceRef)) then
begin
  diInterfaceRef._AddRef();   // removed when diInterface falls out of scope
  ...
end
else
begin  // it doesn't support the interface!
  ...
end;
```

Whether you want to catch exceptions (which some people like, some people don't - it does make the code less linear), or code for `if..else`, is usually a matter of preference. I prefer not to rely on exceptions (but I still have `try..finally` or `try..except` blocks), but of course other opinions are available!

Comment: And when then I should use "as "?

Comment: Use as when your program can't work if the object doesn't support the interface. Otherwise use Supports.

Comment: I see David has shared his wisdom with you while I was updating my answer...

Comment: You should not be calling `_AddRef()` manually on an interface returned by `Supports()`. It will have already had its refcount incremented when `Supports()` exits. Calling `_AddRef()` manually requires a manual `_Release()` to avoid a leak.